# Accessing and modifying a nested hash based on a dot separated string

Tags: perl, variables, strict

I have a string as input, say apple.mango.orange = 100

I also have a hash reference:

> $inst = {
>      'banana' => 2,
>      'guava'  => 3,
>      'apple' => {
>          'mango' => {
>              'orange' => 80
>          }
>       }
>   };

I want to modify the value of orange using the input string. Can someone please help me how I could do this?

I tried splitting the string into (key, value) pair. I then did the following on the key string:

```
my $key2 = "\$inst->{".$key."}";
$key2 =~ s/\./}->{/g;
$$key2 = $value;
```

This does not work as intended. Can someone help me out here? I have read the Perl FAQ about not using a variable value as variable but I am unable to think of an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You are building string that consists of (buggy) Perl code, but you never ask Perl to execute it. ...but that's not the right approach.

```
sub dive_val :lvalue {
   my $p = \shift;
   $p = \($$p->{$_}) for @_;
   $$p
}

my @key = split /\./, "apple.mango.orange";
dive_val($inst, @key) = $value;
```

or

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveVal );

my @key = split /\./, "apple.mango.orange";
DiveVal($inst, map \$_, @key) = $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not only is a symbolic reference a very bad idea here, it doesn't even solve your problem. You're building an *expression* in `$key2`, and just jamming another dollar sign in front of its name won't make perl execute that code. For that you would need `eval`, which is another bad idea

You can install and use the `Data::Diver` module, which does exactly this sort of thing, or you can simply loop over the list of hash keys, picking up a new hash reference each time and assigning the value to the element with the last key

The biggest issue is actually parsing the incoming string into a list of keys and a value. This code implements a subroutine `apply` which applies the implied operation in the string to a nested hash. Unless you are confident of your data, it needs some error checking addingto make sure each of the keys in the list exists. The `Data:;Dumper` output is just to demonstrate the validity of the result

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dumper;

my $inst = { 'banana' => 2, 'guava' => 3, 'apple' => { 'mango' => { 'orange' => 80 } } };

my $s = 'apple.mango.orange = 100';

apply($s, $inst);

print Dumper $inst;

sub apply {
    my ($operation, $data) = @_;
    my ($keys, $val) = $operation =~ /([\w.]+)\s*=\s*(\d+)/;

    my @keys = split /\./, $keys;
    my $last = pop @keys;

    my $hash = $data;
    $hash = $hash->{$_} for @keys;
    $hash->{$last} = $val;
}
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'banana' => 2,
          'apple' => {
                       'mango' => {
                                    'orange' => '100'
                                  }
                     },
          'guava' => 3
        };
```